# How to put a picture exactly on the road?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maps

I created Custom Pin in Xamarin.Forms.Maps and add my icon. How I can put my icon on the road and and move this icon along.My problem is not with getting accurate data, but with displaying the image itself exactly on the road. For example, if the road is horizontal, then the icon (car) should stand horizontally on the road

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can change the orientation of a pin

Comment: if i can not change the position of the pin, then how can I get the desired result?

Comment: you can change the position, but you can't change the orientation.  A pin usually indicates a fixed point - if you want to display a moving object a pin probably isn't the right solution.

Comment: Please tell me, what I can use to show dynamic icon

Comment: Offhand, I'm not sure.  I'd read the docs for native maps to see what different kind of visual elements they support

Comment: I didn't found any quick way to add marks on the map other than with pins. So, if you use the pins, and have information about the objects in current location (e.g. the road), you can try to redraw/rotate your pin image in accordance with the current road direction.

Comment: what do you mean "redraw"? I thought having a set of pictures with different directions to change the picture of the car with the correct position relative to the road, but I do not know how to determine the direction of the road then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Map Tracking`. It would show the driver route and car position on the map. The car should move according to its current position in the route.

Install the `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps`.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/

[image]

You could download the source file from the GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/MapTrackingSample